# Prove an inequality involving $e$, prime numbers and logarithm

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

We know that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} \leq e$. Using that we need to prove that

$$\log(1+\frac{1}{p-1}) \leq \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p(p-1)}$$ where $p$ is a prime number.

Since $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} \leq e$, $n\log(1+\frac{1}{n}) \leq 1$ so $\log(1+\frac{1}{n}) \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Plugging in $n = p-1$, I get the same result on the right hand side side since it simplifies to $\frac{1}{p-1}$.

Is this correct? Since it seems too easy for me.

Comment: Yes, the inequality simplifies to $\log(1+\frac{1}{p-1}) \leq \frac{1}{p-1}$, which is true. In fact $\log(1+x) \le x$ is a well-known inequality and holds for all real numbers $x > -1$. This has nothing to do with prime numbers.

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: Why did you write the inequality like that if you already know that the RHS simplifies to $\frac{1}{p-1}$?

Comment: That's how it was given in the task.